# Umbraco 4.7.2 AfterSave create and move nodes in year / month structure causes left content tree to reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have this AfterSave event that runs code to classify my news items into year and month nodes. That portion works correctly, but I have a problem because the lfet content tree menu keeps "reloading" showing only the home node.

I've read many posts telling me to use:

```
BasePage.Current.ClientTools.SyncTree(sender.Path, true);
```

Now this logically should work, but it does not.

I've tried calling:

```
umbraco.library.RefreshContent();
```

Before calling SyncTree, but did not help.

I've gotten "acceptable" results with this:

```
string _returnUrl = "editContent.aspx?id=" + sender.Id.ToString() + "&isNew=true";
BasePage.Current.ClientTools.ChangeContentFrameUrl(_returnUrl);
```

But that is some freaky hacky code.

Can someone shed some light on the difficulties here?

Thanks!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer the question but did you know there were Umbraco packages that did exactly this for you? See http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/datefolders it does exactly what you are after.

Comment: @Digbyswift Yes I tried to install that package, did'nt get it to run, but this website is in french so I need month names in french and I think this package uses numbers. Also the code to write for this is so simple I really thought it would work right away, but these quirky behaviors are a real time sink :(

Comment: But looking at that package's source code I see that they use the same hack as me... (sad sigh)

Comment: Just a small note, you can quite easily convert a date to its language month equivalent which is why it is preferable to use a number.   Look into `ToString()` on a date.